# Android Content provide leading to SecurityException: Permission Denial if not used immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

In my Android Manifest I registered my Activity for being able to "open" specific files.
This all works fine. When I receive the new Intent and read the file data from the intent via

```
BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(contentResolver.openInputStream(intent.data)))
```

it works fine.
However, for a better view flow, I wanted to store the URI of the intent and show it in another view (asking the user how to proceed with the file). So I store this intent.data as a String and open another view first.

However, once the view is opened, I bascially call the same thing

```
val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(act.contentResolver.openInputStream(fileUri)))
```

but here I get an exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading [FileBrowserApp I used for "opening the file"] uri content://... from pid=5242, uid=10159 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

So it feels like *the URI is somehow expired* or such thing? Is this actually the case? **Do I have to read the file directly when I receive the Intent?** I was hoping for a way to keep the URI until I want to read the file.

Comment: "and open another view first" -- do you mean "and open another *activity* first"?

Comment: Yes its normal that uri permissions expire and are not forwardable to other activities.

Comment: Thanks. And under which condition they expire? I really use this function to store the URI, then show another FRAGMENT (same Activity, no new Intent) and in that Fragment I use the URI for loading the file but it expired already. So I assumed, that must happen pretty fast. Is there a specific (lifecycle) call that invalidates the intent (e.g. onResume ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Turns out, it is not a problem of an expiring Intent or anything like that. Instead my own "processing" changed the path.

What I did was taking the incoming Intent data as `Uri`. Later I fetched the provider path from that `Uri` again. However this caused a transformation of the query (instead of leaving it as a String in the first place) breaking the path.

In short: the problem is the URL encoding/decoding.

The original intent path (opened via the TotalComander - hence the *com.ghisler* path) looked like this:

```
content://com.ghisler.files/tree/primary%3A/document/primary%3Astorage%2Femulated%2F0%2Fbackup.bak
```

However getting the path from the `Uri` the colons were decoded leaving an output path of this:

```
content://com.ghisler.files/tree/primary:/document/primary:storage/emulated/0/backup.bak
```

You can clearly see the different encoding. As a consequence **the file path was simply not the same after fetching it from the Uri again**. This was causing the Exception - not an invalidation of the intent.